# Restarting Apache Using PHP in IIS

Tags: php, iis-7, exec, apache2.2

I'm trying to restart my Apache2.2 webserver using a bat file that is being called by a PHP running in IIS using exec(), Apache and IIS is in the same server.

PHP code

`exec("cmd /c restart.bat");`

bat file

`"PATH_TO_APACHE\bin\httpd.exe" -k restart -n Apache2.2`

When I load my php via http to restart, I get an "Unable to open logs" error in my Apache error log file.

Majority of my search results say that there is a port 80 conflict however when I do a netstat there is none, my IIS is listening to a different port. Double-clicking the .bat file works, but running it from the PHP gets the error. Any ideas? Please advise.

Comment: Possibly because the bat is then run under IUSR?

Comment: I've added permission to the cmd.exe as well but I get the same error, added NETWORK SERVICE and IUSR in the Security tab

Comment: Not sure if this help, but I once had to launch a background process (`start /B php longtimejob.php` in bat) and was not successful using `exec`, `system`, `passthru`. Finally I used `pclose(popen("work.bat","r"))` and worked. So maybe you can give `popen` and `proc_open` a try.

Comment: I get the same error "Unable to open logs", could be a permission problem but I'm not sure what else to grant permission.

Comment: Install apache as a service and use `net stop`; `net start` to restart the apache service. This should help you to better clarify on permissions. I suspect that apache actually needs some more rights. Check the permissions of the error log file for example.

Comment: net stop and net start work fine but it takes around 30-40 seconds to restart the service from http, too long. so im looking for an alternative. running the bat file not using the admin account will give me the same error as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS runs all executable scripts under the context of a specified user, usually this is the IUSR_[MACHINENAME] account.
This account can be changed in the IIS configuration in the pool configuration.

The problem you're running into is probably that this user is not allowed to access the log file location.

To track this problem down I would:
1. (dangerous, use only for testing): put the IUSR account in the local administrators group. test again. if it works, you know it is a permission problem.
2. Try using the runas command to run cmd.exe as the IUSR user and execute your command in the console window, that way you see all error messages and test more easily.
3. allow IUSR to write to the apache log location.

A whole different attempt would be to create a marker file in PHP, and use a scheduled task run as Administrator to restart apache if that marker file exists. That way you do not need to give the IUSR account more permissions and have a separate code handling the restart.

Comment: Thanks man, you gave me the idea, I went to check the Application Pool settings in the IIS and changed NetworkService to LocalSystem for that particular application and it worked.